# MailChimp Template looks wrong in Outlook and okay in all browsers

Tags: outlook, mailchimp

I have a hard time finding out why my html+css looks fine in a browser and in the mailchimp preview function but looks ugly in the inbox of outlook.

Are there some things that cant be done in a html outlook email?

Here's the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Scandia Housing</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
 background:#eeeeee;
 margin:0; padding:0;
}

a {
 color:#2f894d;
 text-decoration:none;
}

h2 {
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:18px;
 color:#2d4760;
 font-weight:lighter;
}

h3 {
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:15px;
 color:#2d4760;
 font-weight:lighter;
}



#headtext {
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:10px;
 color:#9aaec2;
 text-align:center;
 width:720px; display:block;
 clear:both; margin:auto;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content {
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
 background:#fff;
 width:720px;
}

#rowbox1 {
 padding:0;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-size:11px;
 margin-top:30px;
 width:720px; height:250px;
 display:block;
}

#rowbox2, #rowbox3, #rowbox4 {
 padding:0;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-size:11px;
 margin-top:20px;
 width:720px; height:210px;
 display:block;
}

#rowbox1 {
 background:url(http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/rowboxbg.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

#a1 img, #c1 img, #d1 img, #e1 img {
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

#b1 img {
 margin-left:10px;
}

#a1, #b1, #c1, #d1, #e1 {
 color:#606060;
 width:350px; height:240px;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;

}

#b1, #c1, #d1, #e1 {
 background:url(http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/boxbg.png) bottom;
 width:380px; height:170px;
 padding:10px;
}

#a1 h2, #b1 h3, #c1 h3, #d1 h3, #e1 h3 {
 margin:0; padding:0;
}

#a2 h2, #b2 h3, #c2 h3, #d2 h3, #e2 h3 {
 margin:0; padding:0;
}

#a2, #b2, #c2, #d2, #e2 {
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-size:11px;
 color:#2d4760;
 width:230px;
 height:190px;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:20px;
}

#a2, #b2, #c2, #d2, #e2 {
 background:url(http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/line.png) bottom no-repeat ;
}

#a2 {
 background:url(http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/listbox.png) no-repeat;
 width:260px; height:220px;
 margin-left:70px;
}

#b1 {
 height:210px;
}

#b2 {
 width:268px; height:210px;
}

#a2 h3 {
 margin:5px 0 0 10px; padding:0;
}

#a2 ul {
 margin:0; padding:0;
 margin:20px 0 0 30px;
}

#a2 h3 {
 color:#fff;
}

#footer {
 text-align:center;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background:url(http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/footer.png);
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

      <div id="headtext"><a href="*|ARCHIVE|*">Hvis du modtager denne email, er du blevet tilmeldt Scandia Housings nyhedsbrev.<br />
      Har du problemer med at få vist dete nyhedsbrev, så klik her og få det vist i din browser.</a></div>

<div id="content"><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/header.png" width="720" height="137" />

            <div id="rowbox1">
              <div id="a1">
              <h2>Velkommen til vores nyhedsbrev </h2>
              <p><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/peter.gif" width="119" height="176" align="left" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc ing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque  lorem et arcu. Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. </p>
              <p>Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhonc us, viverra a risus. <img style="margin-top:20px;" src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/petersign.png" width="112" height="50" /><br />
              </p>
              </div>

              <div id="a2">
                <h3>Nyt fra Scandia Housing </h3>
                <ul>
                  <li>Lejemarkedet om 5 år</li>
                  <li>Regeringen vil lokke udenlandsk talent til Danmark</li>
                  <li>Århus Universitet kommenterer regerings-planerne</li>
                  <li>Fokus på boligen</li>
                  <li>Scandia Housing vokser</li>
                  <li>Travl periode i udsigt</li>
                  <li>Lektor Morten Skak's antagelser</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </div>


<div id="rowbox2">
              <div id="b1">
              <h3><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/person1.gif" width="118" height="178" align="right" />Århus Universitet kommenterer <br />
                regeringsplanerne</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
              <p>Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. Quisque leo tellus.</p>
              <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
          </div>

              <div id="b2">
                <img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/pictures.png" width="268" height="210" />
</div>
        </div>

<div id="rowbox3">
              <div id="c1">
              <h3>Fokus på boligen</h3>
              <p><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/house.gif" width="138" height="83" align="left" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur      adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis      eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum      enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu.      Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. </p>
              <p> Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus, viverra a risus.  Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu.</p>
              <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
          </div>

              <div id="c2">
                <h3>Travl periode i udsigt</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. </p>
                <p>Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus.</p>
                <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rowbox3">
              <div id="c1">
              <h3>Scandia Housing vokser</h3>
              <p><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/house2.gif" width="102" height="136" align="left" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. </p>
              <p>Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus, viverra a risus. </p>
              <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
          </div>

          <div id="c2">
            <h3>HR chefens top 5 liste</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. </p>
                <p>Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus.</p>
                <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rowbox3">
              <div id="c1">
              <h3>Lektor Morten Skak's antagelser</h3>
              <p><img src="http://www.scandiahousing.com/DND/nyhedsbrev/images/house2.gif" width="102" height="136" align="left" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. </p>
              <p>Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus, viverra a risus. </p>
              <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
          </div>

          <div id="c2">
            <h3>Lejemarkedet om 5 år</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla congue, sem quis eleifend aliquam, orci leo vestibulum enim, at ullamcorper neque lorem et arcu. </p>
                <p>Nunc molestie ultrices rutrum. Quisque leo tellus, eleifend vel scelerisque rhoncus.</p>
                <p><a href="#">&gt;&gt; Læs yderligere her</a></p>
          </div>
  </div>

        <div id="footer">Capella Huset • Indiakaj 1 • 2100 København Ø • Danmark • Telefon: (+45) 33 93 11 81<br />
          Vestergade 19B • 8000 Århus C • Danmark • Telefon: (+45) 72 30 04 88<br />
          Telefax København: (+45) 33 93 14 46 Telefax Århus (+45) 86 27 11 87: • e-mail: scandiahousing@scandiahousing.com<br />
  </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In the current version I have hardcoded all the images paths and they are showing correctly.

It is the formatting that goes completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Outlook?  2007 uses Word to render HTML email and can't handle floats or positions and sometimes background images...among a host of other things.  I've found the best way to generate HTML email is to write it like a website from 2000.  Table based layouts etc...